# 403 forbidden for nginx locations

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean

I have an nginx `sites-enabled/default` configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name localhost;


        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
        location ~ /anotherroute {
                alias /home/anotherroute/public;
                index index.html;
        }
}
```

When I access `http://myipaddress/anotherroute` it works fine but when I do `http://myipaddress/anotherroute/yetanotherroute` it comes back as `403 forbidden`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your folder `yetanotherroute` is existed, make sure you have files `index.php` or `index.html` already

Otherwise you should specified a file name such as: `http://myipaddress/anotherroute/yetanotherroute/somefile.php`